# how to browse the files that are already mounted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I'm using dual boot with both Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.0. I have mounted all the partitions through the file manager and I want to access those partitions through the terminal like in windows cmd if I want to shift partitions like c: ,d: or e: .

How can I perform the similar function on terminal? At present I can work only with the home directory. Even though if I change the path using `cd /media`, I  can't access the partitions through the disk names.

For example, I have a  the disk that is named as games and softs. If I have to view the files inside that partition what is the command i have to use?

Comment: If you mount the partitions into sub folders of your home folder, you can browse your files as if they were locally stored and you can name the folders anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you are using Linux, you have to forget the Windows concept.
If you mount a partition using nautilus, it gets mounted at `/media/$USER/` not in `/media`. It will get mounted at some other place only if you are  defining the mount-point in `mount` command or in `/etc/fstab` file.

So if you want to `cd` to some partition using terminal, use

```
cd /media/$USER/<partition_name>
```

For example

```
cd /media/$USER/games/
```